# How do I resize a custom control I've built

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, custom-controls

I'm resizing my custom control using the following code:

```
private void Form1_Resize_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    textBox1.Text = this.Width.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = (this.Height - 200).ToString();

   canvas21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width,  this.ClientSize.Height - this.Top - 15);

    canvas21.Invalidate();

}
```

I just want the top left corner of the custom control(0, 105) to stay in place, and the control to resize along with the form, but for some reason this does not work. When I resize the control stays in place, but automatically resizes to fill out the rest of the form.

[image: Overview of form layout]

Is there any way to get a list of everything that affects the size of a usercontrol. In order to search for other places the size i set, which i might have overlooked?

Comment: Have you investigated the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties already? Using one or both of those is *far* easier than manually implementing the resizing logic in the `Resize` event like we had to do for years before.

Comment: @Cody - i've tried both of these, but i can't get the result i want. See my answer to ho1.

Comment: Pretty unclear what is being asked.  The code snippet is definitely wrong, it should use ClientSize and subtract the Left and Top property values of the control.

Comment: @Hans - I've added a small image to describe my problem, and changed the code. I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your control to always resize with the form, you can use the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property to set it to be anchored to one or more sides of the form so that you don't have to have your own resizing code (assuming that the standard resizing functionality you get with this fits your needs).

You have to make sure that the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) property isn't set though, otherwise it might fill the whole form (or one side of the form depending on the setting).

Comment: i've tried using the Anchor property, but it still fills out the rest of the form in the bottom and to the right. I have a tabControl in the top, a custom control under it and a label below the custom control. I want the custom control to fill out the form except for 15 pixels in the bottom.

Comment: @bildsoe: So have you made sure that the `Dock` property isn't set?

Comment: @bildsoe: Just to clarify, the `Dock` property will override the `Anchor` property. If that's not set in the properties I'd do a search of the code to make sure that it's not being set somewhere else and I'd also suggest a search through the code for any instances of where you set any properties of that control (including inside the control itself!) to see if you set the `Dock` or `Size` properties somewhere in them that could be the reason.

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna do that, but i'm almost sure i don't set them, and that all dock properties is set to none.

Comment: @Bildsoe: If you're still having this problem, I'd suggest that you try creating a new custom control and insert it instead of your current custom control. Also take your current custom control and insert it into a new Form (preferably in a completely separate project). This might help you get certainty of where the issue is which might help you track it down. And if the issue is in the control, try commenting out bits of the code until it stops happening (no matter how unrelated the code looks) happening.

Answer (score 4):

There's really no reason why setting the height and then anchoring to every side (with docking set to none) shouldn't work.

However, I did notice an error in the logic of your provided code.  You have:

```
canvas21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width,  this.ClientSize.Height - this.Top - 15);
```

When it should actually be:

```
canvas21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width,  this.ClientSize.Height - this.canvas21.Top - 15);
```

You were just taking the top of the form, rather than the top of canvas21, which is what you need.

That seems to do exactly what you want, at least from my standpoint.  If it doesn't quite work, is it simply not resizing at all for you or is it resizing to the wrong size?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Anchor property is the better way to go if you can set it.  The ones to lock are

```
left, top, right, bottom (all!)
```

Anchor keeps you control x units form the side that you have locked, so that it is always the same distance from the sides.

If that is not an option, or just to get your code going, try this

```
private void Form1_Resize_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = this.Width.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = (this.Height - 200).ToString();

    int iTop = canvas21.Top;
    int iLeft = canvas21.Left;
    // - 200 - iTop keeps it 200 from the bottom, -iLeft keeps i stuck to right
    canvas21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width -iLeft, this.Height-200 -iTop);
    canvas21.Left = iLeft;   // move back
    canvas21.Top = iTop;   // move back
    canvas21.Invalidate();
}
```

To keep it `15 pixels in the bottom`, change `200` above to `15`. Or, set it at 15 at design time or via code, the activate the `bottom` anchor.

Comment: @cyberwiki - It didn't work. I'm searching for places where i set the size or Dock, but can't find any, so that doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

For controls other than your custom control can you get it to resize properly? For example if you put in a richtextbox and set Anchor accordingly (All) will it resize properly for you? If it does then there must be somthing fishy with the sizing of your control, BUT you could maybe cheat it by doing this...

1. Create a Panel that is the exact size and Anchoring you would like from your control.
2. Add your control to the Panel and set Dock to "Fill". Effectively you will fill the panel with your control and use the panel to control resizing on the form.

If of course your panel doesn't resize properly either then this won't work for you. Granted this is likely a workaround to an underlying code issue that in a perfect world would be remidied on the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at resizing a user control, and I'm using many different events to handle this (eg. OnSizeChanged, OnFontChanged, OnTextChanged)

Depending on how your text Boxes fit in your control will make a difference, but if your primary container has the property AutoScaleMode or AutoSize then you may find you are not catching all the relevant events.

I appologise in advance if I'm off-beam as I'm new to this sort of thing.

ps. I didn't find your post initially as I'd been looking at tags Windows-forms-designer and custom-control.  I really don't know which tags I should use and can't use all the possibilities as the limit of 5 takes over!

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you're going to kick yourself. You don't want ClientSize.Height - **Top** - 15, you want ClientSize.Height - **canvas21.Top** - 15. That's it!

```
private void Form1_Resize_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = this.Width.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = (this.Height - 200).ToString();

    canvas21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width,  
        this.ClientSize.Height - canvas21.Top - 15);

    canvas21.Invalidate();
}
```